# Try to get value from another model but it display error which say "Property "FeeRemissionGroup.class_english_name" is not defined."

Tags: php, yii

I try to get the value from `ClassM` model but it displays an error:

> Property "FeeRemissionGroup.class_english_name" is not defined.

`FeeRemissionGroup` works, but can't get it from `ClassM`.

```
echo $form ->dropDownListRow($model, 'fee_remission_group_code', FeeRemissionGroup::model()->getFeeRemissionGroup(), array('class'=>'span3'));     
echo $form ->dropDownListRow($model, 'class_english_name', ClassM::model()->listClass(), array('class'=>'span5'));
```

Any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: define  public $class_english_name  in  FeeRemissionGroup model ,

Comment: is not working...

Comment: the code you provided  seems don't refer to  FeeRemissionGroup.class_english_name ..   where in the code  you are try accessing this attribute .. ?

Comment: Because I want to get the value from another model 'ClassM', ClassM model got 'class_english_name' attribute but the problem is the error not defined.

Comment: in your code, $model is what? in $model variable which model is passed?